# When someone moves their hands too much as the speak

Tags: word-usage, word-choice, sentence-construction, word-request, word-meaning

Lets suppose someone moves his hands while he is speaking to you or somebody else and then the extent and they way he is doing that starts getting on your nerves. 
I wonder how would you imply that message to someone who is talking to you?

I can make up some choices, however I have no idea if they make sense to you:

- That guy is too [animated](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/animated) and that's getting on my nerves.
- That guys [gesticulations](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/gesticulate) are getting on my nerves.
- That guy's hand movements are getting on my nerves.

Please let me know what is / are the common way(s) to convey this message?

Comment: I would use the second option. Animation doesn't necessarily involve gesticulating a lot.

Comment: This reminds me of the idiom, "if you tied his hands, he couldn't talk."